# Trying to parse XML data with Java - Getting error: "The method getNodeType() is undefined for the type NodeList"

Tags: java, xml

I'm just starting out with learning how to process/parse XML data in Java. I'm getting the error, "*The method getNodeType() is undefined for the type NodeList*" on the line, after my for-loop, that contains:

**if (n.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE){**

The type of error seems like I forgot to import something, but I believe I got everything. I am using an XML example from microsoft, in the following link:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms762271(v=vs.85).aspx

Thanks in advance.

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;

public class Files {

    public static void main (String [] args) throws IOException, ParserConfigurationException{

    String address = "/home/leo/workspace/Test/Files/src/file.xml";

    File xmlFile = new File(address);

    DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder dBuilder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = dBuilder.parse(xmlFile);

    doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

    System.out.println(doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());

    NodeList n = doc.getElementsByTagName("book id");

    for (int temp = 0; temp < n.getLength(); temp++){
        System.out.println(n.item(temp));

    if (n.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE){

        Element e = (Element) n;

        System.out.println("author : " + e.getAttribute("author"));
        System.out.println("title : " + e.getAttribute("title") );
        System.out.println("genre : " + e.getAttribute("genre"));
        System.out.println("price : " + e.getAttribute("price"));
        System.out.println("publish_date : " + e.getAttribute("publish_date"));
        System.out.println("description : " + e.getAttribute("description"));

             }
        }

    }   

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `getNodeType()` on a `NodeList` object (n).

You need to call this function on a `Node` object. Example :

```
n.item(temp).getNodeType();
```

Comment: Thanks, that fixed the error. As I said before, I'm new to XML parsing in Java, and am just following online code/tutorials. I am currently only printing out "catalog." If you, or someone else could point me in the right direction, it would be appreciated.

Comment: @user2411290 You should post another question about this problem since this one was about the getNodeType() function. Also, please consider accepting this solution if it worked for you. Thanks!